# Focus of Cursor in 508 Compliance Testing

Tags: section508, manual-testing

Consider there are *Create/Modify links* in the GUI and clicking those links Opens up a Create/Modify page. Through tabbing, when the ***focus ring*** is on *Create/Modify link*, i pushed enter button. What should be the Default Focus in the Newly opened *Create/Modify* page ??

Is there any Rules/Standards of **508 compliance** for default focus in the New Page or It depends on the particular *Information System* developed ??

Answer (score 0):

The default focus should be in the beginning of the Create/Modify page. The page contents should be automatically read out by the screen reader. I am not aware of any rules regarding this but this is normally the acceptance criteria that 508 testers specify.

Answer (score 0):

The focus depends on the flow that you have used in your website.

Check the following URL for more info - "http://www.epa.gov/inter508/toolkit/508_compliance_toolkit_web_apps.htm"

Answer (score 0):

It should be as per client requirement. But mostly by default focus should be in first field. And if first field is DDL then it should be second field.